# Capybara test succeeds and fails randomly

Tags: testing, capybara

I have some tests in Capybara.

Specifically I have two 'describe' methods.

These two test sometimes run fine, but sometimes they fail and I don't understand why as I don't change them.
This makes my testing environment completely unreliable.

Does somebody suggest what can be the reason?

I mean, I think that sometimes some queries like expect.to have_css() run before that the page is completely loaded. Is that possible?

Luca

Comment: It's possible if you have a lot of ajax-y operations going on.  AngularJS apps can cause problems with Capybara.

If you have any "loading spinners" in your app, those are helpful to wait on before moving forward with some steps in your tests.

Otherwise I recommend outputting more log messages in your specs to narrow down where and why they are failing.

Comment: Well, you are right. Actually the JS side is wide and wild. No AngularJS nor "loading spinners": I'll try to implement some so to see if they help.

Answer (score 0):

What's your timeout set to? You can override it with.

```
using_wait_time(30) do
  expect(page).to have_css('selector')
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does't seem to improve that much. I have been either trying  to implement the a "wait for ajax" method (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara) but it doesn't seem to change much.